# doing the javascript/angular part with Polymer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

so i just found out about polymer and it looks realy cool but the thing is i couldn't figure out if its using javascript or its own unique language.
so what script language polymer using? i like angular and i saw that polymer script is like angular script so i didn't realized if im suppose to use javascript angular or polymer script...

yo-greeting file:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
 <polymer-element name="yo-greeting"  attributes="">
 <template>
<style>
  /* styles for the custom element itself - lowest specificity */
  :host { display: block; }
  /*
  style if an ancestor has the different class
  :host-context(.different) { }
  */
  .imgWidth {
    width: 100%;
  }
core-header-panel {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}
core-toolbar {
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: white;
}
#tabs {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
</style>
<img src="../images/lion.jpg" alt="" class="imgWidth" />
<paper-tabs selected="{{selectedPage}}">
  <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
<core-pages selected="{{selectedPage}}">
  <div class="red_tab">One</div>
  <div class="blue_tab">Two</div>
  <div class="black_tab">Three</div>
</core-pages>
 </template>
  <script>
 Polymer({
  selectedPage: 1
});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

index file:

```
                   <!doctype html>
                    <html class="no-js">

                    <head>
                      <meta charset="utf-8">
                      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                      <title>Polymer WebApp</title>
                      <meta name="description" content="">
                      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                      <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

                      <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
                      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
                      <!-- endbuild-->

                      <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
                      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
                      <!-- build:vulcanized elements/elements.vulcanized.html -->
                      <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
                      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
                      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-media-query/core-media-query.html">  
                      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-list/core-list.html">
                      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html">
                      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-selector/core-selector.html">
                      <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
                      <!-- endbuild-->
                    </head>

                    <body unresolved>

                      <div class="hero-unit">
                        <yo-greeting></yo-greeting>
                        <!-- <p>You now have</p>
                        <yo-list></yo-list> -->
                      </div>

                      <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
                      <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
                      <!-- endbuild-->
                    </body>

                    </html>
```

elements file:

```
<link rel="import" href="yo-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="yo-greeting.html">
```

i want that when i press on one of these tabs the core-pages will switch using polymer.
how do i do that the best way possible?
also - why my core-pages is not like that demo in the polymer site - http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-pages?
i installed it using bower and linked it just like the i linked the paper-tabs. its just showing one and does not switch when pressed.

thanks for all your help.

Comment: Have you gone through their tutorial? http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html

Comment: yes. tried and tried but the scripts there doesn't seems to work for me.i followed the tutorial step one but when i add the script tag it returns:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there is no such thing as *"Polymer Script"*. You write the code for your custom components in a language like JavaScript or Dart (or CoffeeScript or TypeScript or...)

There is a concept called [*"Polymer Expressions"*](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html), which is the syntax inside the mustache (`{{ }}`) binding expressions. This is a subset of the JavaScript language with some additions like [filters](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#filters) and they are similar to the AngularJS binding expressions.

To switch between the pages with your tabs, simply set up a binding between the `selected` properties of these elements. Currently you are setting the `selected` attribute of `<core-pages>` to 0, but nothing is changing it later on.

```
<polymer-element name="yo-greeting">
  <template>
    ...
    <paper-tabs selected="{{selectedPage}}">
      <paper-tab>TAB 1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>TAB 2</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>TAB 3</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
    <core-pages selected="{{selectedPage}}">
      <div class="red_tab">One</div>
      <div class="blue_tab">Two</div>
      <div class="black_tab">Three</div>
    </core-pages>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('yo-greeting', {
      selectedPage: 0
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Whenever the tab selection changes this automagically updates the selected core page. This is done by binding the `selected` attributes to the `selectedPage` property of the `yo-greeting` element.

Comment: your code is not working for me and i dont know why... there is no errors in the console.if i put the selectedPage to 1 it does change the core-pages to the 'Two' page.

Comment: Could you please update your question so that it shows us the complete code. Thank you.

Comment: actually, im getting this warning in the console, think it may has something to do with it:Attributes on core-pages were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.

Comment: Move the `<link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">` line behind all other `<link...>` lines. You need to import the elements that are used in your custom element first.